# EKS Cluster with Private Subnets: Issue Deploying a Public LoadBalancer Using Ingres

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I've set up an EKS cluster which consists of 3 private subnets and spans across 3 nodes. My aim is to deploy a public load balancer using ingress. However, during deployment, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed build model due to couldn't auto-discover subnets: unable to discover at least one subnet.
```

From my understanding, this might be because I don't have a public subnet with the necessary tags `(e.g., kubernetes.io/role/elb set to 1).`

Since I currently cannot add a new public subnet to the existing cluster, I'm considering creating a public subnet and adding the appropriate tags. This way, the AWS load balancer might be able to create the lb in the public subnet.

is it recommended to do it or do i have to create a new cluster with 3 private and 2 public subnets?

Appreciate your help!